# Ошибка в модули mCrypt при установке opencart

Tags: php, opencart, centos, centos7

При установке opencart в модуле mCrypt возникла ошибка. Нашёл такое решение - удалить файл и скопировать с гитхаба содержимое и заменить в system/library/encryption.php. Подскажите как это сделать, чтоб не поудалять лишнего? Или может есть другой вариант решения проблемы?

Скопировать отсюда - https://github.com/ocStore/ocStore/blob/ocstore-3-0-2-0/upload/system/library/encryption.php

Answer (score 0):

Решил:

```
[root@cntos library]# rm encryption.php
rm: remove regular file ‘encryption.php’? y

[root@cntos library]# curl -O https://github.com/ocStore/ocStore/blob/ocstore-3-0-2-0/upload/system/library/encryption.php

[root@cntos library]# systemctl restart httpd
```